# How to delete data using Vue.axios.delete()

Tags: vuejs2, axios, json-server

I am new to vuejs. I am having trouble deleting `json` data from a fakeserve by using `axios.delete()`.

I tried doing this :-

```js
axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users/', {params: {id:  this.idToDelete} })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

This is my html:-

```html
<v-text-field v-model="idToDelete" type="number" hide-details outline 
label="Enter Id to delete"></v-text-field>
<v-btn @click="userIdtoDelete()" color="error">Delete</v-btn>
```

This is my javascript (src/views/pages/Delete.vue):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

export default {
data () {
    return {
        idToDelete: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    userIdtoDelete () {

    axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users/', {params: {id:  this.idToDelete} })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            //alert('response = ' + response)
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
            //alert('error = ' + error)
        })
     }
   }
}
```

My code is in https://github.com/boidurja/users.git

And fakeserver is in https://github.com/boidurja/fakeserver.git

When I click the delete button data is not getting deleted and I am getting the following error message:-

> DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/?id=3 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This seems to be more an issue with your server-side code. Can you not debug why you're getting a 404 response?

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) automatically creates [routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#routes) in a [RESTful format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods), eg

```
GET    /users
GET    /users/1
POST   /users
PUT    /users/1
PATCH  /users/1
DELETE /users/1
```

So with that in mind, you should be using

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/users/${encodeURIComponent(this.idToDelete)}`)
    .then(res => { console.log(res) })
    .catch(err => { console.error(err) })
```

Comment: I tried deleting id = 3. But it's deleting ids 2, and 3, and 4.What could we do to fix it.Thanks

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar doesn't happen for me when I test locally. Check your browser's _Network_ console. What `DELETE` requests are being sent? Do they have the correct id's appended to the request

Comment: Hello @Phil These are the screenshots of my Network console: https://ibb.co/6y0DVBj and https://ibb.co/GPmG6VH. Seems like they have the correct id's appended to the request.

Comment: All looks good. How exactly are you verifying that it's deleting the wrong records? Are you sure your user records all have unique id's?

Comment: I can see in the fake server http://localhost:3000/users that it's deleting the wrong records. User records all have unique id's.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? What are you seeing and where?

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar can you please provide some screenshots because I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying

Comment: Screenshot1: https://ibb.co/hdHvMVW, screenshot2:https://ibb.co/mFNczFz. When I delete the record with "id": "2", "id": "4" also gets deleted.

Comment: Your screenshots provide no context. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57140226/edit) and step through what happens and when. For example... 1) Here's my initial data (screenshot from postman). 2) I enter an ID and click the button. 3) Here's the `DELETE` request (network console screenshot). 4) Here's what the data looks like now (screenshot from postman)

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar at this stage though, unless there's something you're omitting from your question, you've found a bug in JSON Server. You should check their [issue list](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+delete) to see if it's already been logged. **Edit:** [This bug looks likely](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/725)

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is that you are calling a function inline with `()` vue does this for you, try

```
<v-btn @click="userIdtoDelete" color="error">Delete</v-btn>
```

I think you are triggering the function twice.

In addition, you can try instead of using `v-model` to catch the `id` directly in the function like `userIdtoDelete($event.target.value)`

Comment: exactly as I wrote, you give the function that value, take off the v-model and then use that in your `userIdtoDelete` function as `userIdtoDelete (id){...}`

Comment: You can bind directly to the method name or call it inline. It doesn't make a difference - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

Comment: @Michael I tried it this way: <v-text-field @blur="userIdtoDelete($event.target.value)" type="number" hide-details outline label="Enter Id to delete"></v-text-field> userIdtoDelete (id){ Vue.axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users/' + id) } But it's deleting multiple records with different id's.

Comment: Comment everything out of your function, console log what the function receives, we can proceed from there.

Comment: Commented everything out of the function.

Comment: what does the console show that the function receives?